# Highlighting Elements Within Shadow DOMs - How to Achieve This Without Event Listeners?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, shadow-dom

I am working on a project where I need to highlight elements within both regular DOM and shadow DOM. Currently, I have a function that binds event listeners to elements within shadow DOMs, but I want to modify it to add a class that highlights the elements instead of attaching event listeners.

Here is the function I have for attaching event listeners to shadow DOMs:

```
function injectToShadowDoms(doc, eventName, listener, capture) {
  var allElements = doc.all;
  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    if (element.shadowRoot) {
      element.shadowRoot.addEventListener(eventName, listener, capture);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to enhance this function to add a class that highlights elements within shadow DOMs. Additionally, I have a separate function (highlightElementsInShadow) for highlighting elements within a shadow DOM using a class.

Here is the modified code for adding a class instead of attaching event listeners:

```
function injectToShadowDoms(doc, highlightClass) {
  var allElements = doc.all;
  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    if (element.shadowRoot) {
      highlightElementsInShadow(element.shadowRoot, highlightClass);
    }
  }
}

function highlightElementsInShadow(shadowRoot, highlightClass) {
  var allShadowElements = shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('*');
  allShadowElements.forEach(function (shadowElement) {
    shadowElement.classList.add(highlightClass);
  });
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly modify the injectToShadowDoms function to achieve the desired highlighting effect without using event listeners.

Comment: Let components control their own behavior. In other words, the component adds a listener and sets a class. Show us your component.